# Что-то как откуда-то/где-то — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятые

*Он рассказал анекдот(,) как из жизни.

Мне попался пример(,) как в том видео.*

Когда я написал такую фразу, я не поставил запятую. Хотелось бы, чтобы оказалось, что я поступил правильно интуитивно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь возможны **варианты**.

1) *Мне попался (такой) пример, как в **том** видео. С ним случилась (такая) история, как в **одном** романе.*

Сравнительный оборот обособляется, он раскрывает **содержание пропущенного указательного** местоимения. Содержание **того конкретного** видео или  романа должно быть дополнительно рассказано или известно.

Пауза не подчеркивается, хотя обозначается (интонация простого предложения). Поэтому оборот кажется необособленным.

2) Сравнить:

*Всё было **как в том видео*** (в составе сказуемого).

*Она мечтала о любви **как в романе*** (о романтической любви). *С ним случилась история **как в кино/в анекдоте*** (киношная/смешная история). Необособленное несогласованное определение, выраженное сравнительным оборотом.

Comment: Спасибо! А в моих примерах без запятой можно?

Comment: В первом примере можно заменить: анекдот как из жизни - жизненный (правдивый) анекдот, здесь обособление не нужно. А во втором предложении оборот обособляется, в ответе я объясняю почему. Там  дается ссылка на подобную ситуацию, но  нет определения предмета.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!